# Callback when DOM is loaded in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I want to have a callback invoked on my react.js component when its DOM element (including all child nodes) is actually loaded on the page and ready. Specifically, I have two components that I want to render the same size, choosing the maximum of whichever component has the larger natural size.

It looks like `componentDidMount` is not really what I want because it is only called once per component, but I want my callback to be called again anytime the component is finished rendering. I thought I could add an `onLoad` event to the top level DOM element, but I guess that only applies for certain elements, like `<body>` and `<img>`.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Looks like a combination of `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` will get the job done. The first is called after the initial rendering, when the DOM is available, the second is called after any subsequent renderings, once the updated DOM is available. In my case, I both have them delegate to a common function to do the same thing.

Comment: but componentDidUpdate will be called many times which is not feasible

Comment: @John in what way is it not feasible?

Comment: @brianmearns
While using a state management library like redux, the parent props can change many times and each time componentDidUpdate would get called. Won't be feasible in this case if all we need is to wait for the initial DOM render. Attaching a load listener in componentDidMount seems better in that case as shown in one of the answers below.

Comment: Does this only work on the top-level component? How does this approach ensure that all of the child components have finished rendering?

Comment: when i use this method, it gave me an maximum depth because it create an infinite loop

Comment: @LuthfiMusafa those methods don't call each other directly, so you must be doing something in them to cause infinite recursion. I'm not sure what that would be because most React methods are event driven, they don't call each other directly afaik. Are you calling `render` in these methods for instance? You should not be, and I'm not sure if or how that would cause infinite recursion, but it's the only thing I can think of off hand.

Comment: @mpelzsherman no, this should work on any component. According to the React docs and my experience, all child components are rendered/updated to DOM elements before either of these methods are called.

Comment: Now you can use the "useEffect" hook to do the same thing (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Answer (score 88):

Add onload listener in componentDidMount

```
class Comp1 extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleLoad = this.handleLoad.bind(this);
 }

 componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('load', this.handleLoad);
 }

 componentWillUnmount() { 
   window.removeEventListener('load', this.handleLoad)  
 }

 handleLoad() {
  $("myclass") //  $ is available here
 }
}
```

Comment: also remember to add remove eventlistener
`componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('load', this.handleLoad)
  }`

Answer (score 28):

A combination of `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` will get the job done in a code with class components.
But if you're writing code in total functional components `the Effect Hook` would do a great job it's the same as `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  // Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:
  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the document title using the browser API
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

> https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: I like the direction of this answer however your example does not solve the problem.

Comment: I think the question is related to load event. With the useEffect hook you detect the moment user access to the 'view/page/....' You are not waiting for all the elements be present in the screen

Comment: This is actually helpful. You can even target a node using document.getElementById and perform an operation with this using this method. Thanks @Hitesh. Very helpful in my case.

Answer (score 6):

I applied componentDidUpdate to table to have all columns same height. it works same as on $(window).load() in jquery.

eg:

```
componentDidUpdate: function() {
        $(".tbl-tr").height($(".tbl-tr ").height());
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `componentDidUpdate` is not called for the initial render, so your function won't be applied until the props or state are _changed_: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: why do you use jquery in react? author asked for React solution, so there is no need to introduce new extra dependencies which in fact are not useful at all

Answer (score 6):

What I have found is that simply wrapping code in the `componentDidMount` or `componentDidUpdate` with a `setTimeout` with a time of 0 milliseconds ensures that the browser DOM has been updated with the React changes before executing the `setTimeout` function.

Like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        $("myclass") //  $ is available here
    }, 0)
}
```

This puts the anonymous function on the JS Event Queue to run immediately after the currently running React stack frame has completed.

Comment: What's the point of the setTimeout? I understand what it does in terms of the event queue, but why do you think that's necessary here? According to the react docs, neither of these methods will be called until the DOM elements are loaded/updated. By adding a setTimeout, you're introducing a race condition with subsequent updates.

Comment: I used this same technique as well for lazy load image. If i call my lazyLoadImages function directly in componentDidMount, the page loading indicator located in the browser tab will keep spinning until all the images are loaded. But if wrap lazyLoadImages function in setTimeout with 100ms argument, this situation is different. The loading indicator will very soon stop spinning while images are started to load at background. setTimeout make the experience better. Binding lazy load function to window onload event does the same, but it doesn't work for a SPA.

Comment: Great technique!

Answer (score 3):

In modern browsers, it should be like

```
try() {
     if (!$("#element").size()) {
       window.requestAnimationFrame(try);
     } else {
       // do your stuff
     }
};

componentDidMount(){
     this.try();
}
```

Comment: heh, except modern browsers don't use jquery =P. It's good tip about using the animation frame though, assuming it should be live updating.

Answer (score 3):

seems it's working to me

```
const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
const [isPageLoaded, setIsPageLoaded] = useState(false); //this helps

useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoaded(true);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoaded) {
        setIsPageLoaded(true);
    }
}, [isLoaded]);
```

Comment: This would work, but chaining two useStates AND two useEffects just to check if the page is loaded is a performance nightmare.

Comment: yes, in my case page is not heavy and it works but what is the real solution? I'm pretty sure there is something but still couldn't find!

Comment: To best honest, I've been looking for the answer myself. Looks like React 18 will bring lazy loading out of the box though.

Comment: if using two usestates is a performance nightmare to you, I can only imagine the complexity of the apps you've developed

Answer (score 1):

The below is what I came up with to wait for when the DOM is ready before trying to get a class using document.getElementsByClassName. I called this function from the componentDidMount() lifecycle method.

```
     changeIcon() {
            if (
                document.getElementsByClassName('YOURCLASSNAME')
                    .length > 0 &&
                document.getElementsByClassName('YOURCLASSNAME').length > 0
            ) {
                document.getElementsByClassName(
                    'YOURCLASSNAME'
                )[0].className = 'YOUR-NEW-CLASSNAME';
                document.getElementsByClassName(
                    'YOUR-OTHER-EXISTING-CLASSNAME'
                )[0].style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                setTimeout(this.changeIcon, 500);
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in app.js [initial js file] below and it will detect the window refresh:

```
    window.onload = () => {
      if (window.location.pathname != "/") {
        window.location = "/";
      }
    };

// const App = (props) => {
```