# Sending API call before page reload or close using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to send information to the backend regarding the state of the application at page reload/close. Is there a way to detect these two actions and call an API before proceeding?

Comment: Does this question help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059762/callback-when-dom-is-loaded-in-react-js

Comment: @AndreM I am looking to call an API before leaving the page not on entering.

Comment: Similar approach, but listen for the `beforeunload` event. `componentWillUnmount()` might do the trick as well, though I haven't tried or compared the scenarios within React.

Answer (score 5):

You can use thew window.unload event (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unload).

Put the code below in some point of you code (I suggest in the index.html or some entry point of the app):

```
window.addEventListener('unload', function(event) {
   //call function to save you state in API or save in localStore
   localStore.setItem('state', JSON.stringify(store.getState())
});
```

I think use componentWillUnmount could not resolve properly your problem, because react could call that event though the browser is not refresh or close.

Comment: Hmm doesn't seem like the scope will allow me to access the component state

Comment: why do you wanna access the component state? you wanna save the whole redux state right? so when you call "let store = createStore(reducers...,....)" in the line below you can add the unload event.

Comment: No I just want to save the Items that were in the cart to the backend. This would be a draft.

Comment: So I suggest you to correct the question.

You can use the same approach to save just a piece of state, sth like "store.getState().cartList". Or you can put this window.unload event in you Cart component (constructor or componentDidMount), but it's not recommended because these react cycle events can be called more than 1 time.

Comment: Adding the listener is giving me problems however. The page is moving before the API has a chance to send.

Comment: The API goes out... but it gets cancelled as the page reloads

Comment: Strange behavior this. Did you try with the beforeunload event?