# REACT- I want to send an API get request every time i refresh the page (F5)

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, server, get

I'm building a sudoku app with REACT and an expressJS server.
I want the board to load the last saved board  everytime the page is refreshed so the user wont lose their data.

i`v managed to send a post request to the seerver and send the  current board, I store the current board in an array (at the server) and i manage to update it every POST request so that everytime a change is accuring withing the board i`m sending a post reques, it works well and the data is stored.

[image]

I tried to use "useeffect" so when i load the page, the client will send a get request to the server and fetch an array of the last stored board.
the problem is it does that once when i load the page, but it doesn`t work when i refresh the page. (F5).

i want to be able to send a get request once every time the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

check this issue if can help by using localstorage to save your data
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45069792/8808725