# Hoisting TypeScript callback function to window object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've been given a working HTML page that has JS code that looks something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function nativeThingEventHandler(event) {
        console.log("event received: " + event);
    }

    window.onload = function() {
        if (typeof nativeThing !== "undefined") {
            console.log("Native thing was found");      
            nativeThing.setListener("nativeThingEventHandler");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Where the `nativeThing` is a native object external to the HTML that does stuff, then calls the `nativeThingEventHandler` (which, as you can see, is defined in the top level of the JS code) callback. I need to integrate this HTML page into a React Typescript project, and I am new to TypeScript. I am having trouble implementing the `nativeThingEventHandler` function so that it can be found by `nativeThing`, so I keep getting an error when the `nativeThing` object sends events back. How can I define the event handler in typescript so that, after the project is built, it can be found in the top level of the JS code?

**Edit for clarification:** The API of nativeObject expects a string in the `setListener` method, and then expects there to be a function with the same name as that string in the top level of the Javascript (not inside of any other functions). So this question is specifically about how to write a typescript function, that, once compiled, will result in the function being placed at the top level of the javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ugly workaround would be to assign your callback function to a variable below `window` by hand:

```
import { nativeThingEventHandler } from 'somewhere';

(window as any).nativeThingEventHandler = nativeThingEventHandler;
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe wasn't clear; will edit my post. The question wasn't how to get the javascript  here to work. It already works. It is how to write typescript that builds to match this javascript, with a function named "nativeObjectEventHandler" at the top level. Unfortunately the nativeObject's API expects a string when setting the listener, and expects to find the function named the same thing as the string in the top level of the script tag.

Comment: Yep, it is currently inside of a module. I thought I could do something like `declare global { function nativeObjectEventHandler(event: any): void; }` at the top of the module, and then implement the function somewhere lower down. But the things I've tried haven't worked, so maybe my understanding is faulty.

Comment: Just saw it! trying now.

Comment: TypeScript declarations, maybe somewhat confusingly, are literally just declarations that never get compiled down to JavaScript (the same applies to type information BTW, so don't bother trying something like `const foo = new T()`)

Comment: Hmm, your answer didn't work for me, but it does seem like it should. Trying to figure out why. Is defining a function on window different than just defining a function at the top level? What you are giving here would compile to something like `<script>window.eventHandler={...}</script>` instead of just `<script>eventHandler={...}</script>`, right?

Comment: It should be equivalent since a named `function` inside a top-level script gets hoisted to `window`. You can check for yourself by declaring `window.nativeThingEventHandler = function()...` in your js version.

Comment: If the above works, I have a hunch that your issue might be with react. In that case, take a shot at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059762/callback-when-dom-is-loaded-in-react-js

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I finally diagnosed the problem. Your solution would have worked, but unfortunately my REAL problem is the fact that this typescript project is being hosted inside of an iframe, whereas the original HTML was not. The `nativeThing` obj isn't able to find the listener function by name if the <script> tag it is contained in is underneath an iframe.

Comment: So, I think my only solution is to write the creator of the `nativeThing` object to ask them to change the `setListener` method so I can pass in a callback function instead of having to pass in a string. Which would be a much better implementation anyway, so I hope they can do it. Accepting your answer. Thanks again for your help!