# How to display a SweetAlert popup on Dom load using Function Component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sweetalert2

I recently started using react so I apologize if this is too "noobish" question. So I am trying to have a SweetAlert popup on path(URL) change is there a way this can be done using functional component?

I already checked
[Callback when DOM is loaded in react.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059762/callback-when-dom-is-loaded-in-react-js)
But this works only for class components..

Comment: The `useEffect()` hook: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible using [`useEffect()` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

> If you’re familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think of `useEffect` Hook as `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount` combined.

Since hooks can only be called within functional components.