# React - correct way to wait for page load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pageload, pageloadstrategy

In React JS, what is the correct way to wait for a page to load before firing any code?

Scenario:
A login service authenticates a user then redirects them (with a cookie), to a React App.
The React App then straight away searches for a cookie and validates it against an endpoint.

But the problem I am getting is when user is authenticated at login service, then forwarded to React App, the App is loading so quick before cookie is even loaded.

What is the right way to fire the code? I tried wrapping in a componentDidMount(), didnt work!

Comment: Did you try listening for 'load' event? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43739277/3113485

Comment: Can you show some of the code you have yet implemented?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest you to use a state in the Main component of your application (usually App.jsx) which will control loading. When you start the app the state will be true and only after checking all you need to check it will beacome false. If state is loading you will show a spinner or whatever you want and when it is not loading, the website:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { loading: true }
    }


    componentDidMount () {
       checkToken()
           .then(() => this.setState({ loading: false });

    }

    if (loading) {
        return <Spinner /> // or whatever you want to show if the app is loading
    }
    return (
        ...rest of you app
    )
}
```

If any doubt just let me know.

Answer (score 7):

you can use Suspense and lazy :)

```
   import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
    
    const OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./OtherComponent'));
    
    function MyComponent() {
      return (
        <div>
          <Suspense fallback={<div>loading...</div>}>
            <OtherComponent />
          </Suspense>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! jsPlumb needs to wait for the document to fully load.

Answer (score 0):

Add this somewhere in the UI tree (maybe add it in the root component itself)

```
// will run once, after app has loaded

useEffect(() => {
  // your code here
}, []);
```