# Axios post is not returning data when used in a function call in a react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

I am using axios post request in my react application. The post request works fine and i get respone data in console log. But i want to return that data to render in web page. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.
Here is my function that makes axios request.

```
function _toRoomName(title) {
const axios = require('axios');
axios({
              method: "POST", 
              url:"hashroomname.php",
              data: {
                roomname: title 
             }
           }).then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data);
                return response.data;
          }).catch((error) => { 
              return error;
           });
}
```

Here is my render method that need to render returned response.

```
<Text className = 'titled'>
    { _toRoomName(title) } //I want result here
 </Text>
```

Comment: maybe , try to convert it to son first, like this : .this(response=>response.json()).    Use this before the current then statement

Comment: well maybe, if the problem is with rendering then instead of returning, you can use the state hook feature of react, here's an ex : https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: Its not working even if i use json format

Comment: Its text that will display automatically after page loads. I cant use click event with this

Comment: well if you want to display text using event, you can always use onclick , it's there in the react, or if you want to call function download then refer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059762/callback-when-dom-is-loaded-in-react-js, is your code anywhere online like stackblitz, it can help all to check the error better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is: 1) make your function asyncronous.

```
async function _toRoomName(title) {
          const axios = require('axios');
            axios({
                  method: "POST", 
                  url:"hashroomname.php",
                  data: {
                    roomname: title 
                 }
               }).then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    return response.data;
              }).catch((error) => { 
                  return error;
               });
    }
```

2)Move your function to componentDidMount() and store the result in state. use that state in render method.

```
componentDidMount() {
const axios = require('axios');
axios({
              method: "POST", 
              url:"hashroomname.php",
              data: {
                roomname: title 
             }
           }).then((response) => {
                this.setState({state:response.data})
                
          }).catch((error) => { 
              return error;
           });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `return` from the function call - you're returning from within the `then` but not the outer promise

```
function _toRoomName(title) {
    return axios({
              method: "POST", 
              url:"hashroomname.php",
              data: {
                roomname: title 
             }
           }).then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data);
                return response.data;
          }).catch((error) => { 
              return error;
           });
}
```

*but* this won't really work. You can't embed the promise within the `<Text>`, you'll need to lift it outside into state

eg

```
const [ data, setData ] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
   _toRoomName(title)
     .then(response => {
       setData(response)
     })
}, [])

return (
  <Text className = 'titled'>
    {data}
  </Text>
)
```

now `data` will be null until loaded, and `<Text>` will be empty until it has the data

Comment: You've probably solved this by now but just in case - you need to import `useState` from react in the same way you import `useEffect` (eg `React.useState` or `import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'`

Comment: after importing i got minified error it dint work. So modified my code and moved axios post request to componentDidMount() component and that worked for me